# Exception error in google doc api

Tags: api, servlets, glassfish

I am new to google api. I am trying to create a simple web application (Java EE) to read DocumentListFeed from google doc. My code in the servlet is:

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {

```
    try 
    {   
        DocsService service = new DocsService("Document List Demo");
        service.setUserCredentials(NAME, PASSWORD);

        response.getWriter().println("helloooooo");


        //URL documentListFeedUrl = new URL("http://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full");     
        URL documentListFeedUrl = new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full?v=3");        
        DocumentListFeed feed = service.getFeed(documentListFeedUrl, DocumentListFeed.class);

        for(DocumentListEntry entry : feed.getEntries())
        {
            response.getWriter().println(entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
        }



    }   

    catch (Exception e)
    {

        response.getWriter().println(e);
    }
}
```

But it is showing me the error:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gdata/client/docs/DocsService

I am using Glassfish server and Ecllipse. And added external jar file: activation.jar, guava-r07.jar, mail.jar, servlet.jar, gdata-client-1.0.jar, gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar, gdata-core-1.0.jar, gdata-media-1.0.jar, gdata-docs-3.0.jar, gdata-docs-meta-3.0.jar.

I have copied this same code to java standard edition and it is working fine. Could please tell me why this thing is not working in Java EE? Is it a problem in GlassFish server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just means that the jars are not present in your Glassfish server classpath.
Add all the jars you listed to yuor glassfish server classpath. Since am not an Glassfish expert i cannot help you in adding the jars to your server.
In case of weblogic, you just need to package all the jars in your project APP-INF directory.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Sajan Chandran. It worked. It is better to add (copy-paste) the jar files directly to the lib folder in project-name\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib